# Voicemeeter Banana Low Volume / Distorted Audio

Tags: audio, mixer

I'm going to try explaining this the best I can. I use Voicemeeter banana and I'm trying to output both my system sound + my microphone. I'm using 1 virtual cable which is set as default in my sound playback, and my voicemeeter output as my default communication. I play music through spotify which goes through the virtual cable and out the voicemeeter output. But the music is really low and kind of distorted. I'm not really sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. (Sorry if I explained that bad)

Comment: Which audio mode are you using? Generally MME is mixed, WDM is exclusive. You'll see it under device selection. I'd also suggest taking a look at the sample rates for your audio devices, and maybe turning up the volume on system volume controls.

Comment: Yeah im using WDM. It's odd, it's quiet and distorted.

Comment: Try MME for a laugh

Comment: to connect a particular device to Voicemeeter, if WDM does not work, you may try KS interface... or MME at last.

Comment: It's really hard to explain. I have my microphone and my system audio going to the microphone output. When people hear the music from my output microphone that is coming from my system audio which is routed to my VB cable. But the sound of the music is distorted and low

Comment: Even if this answer is waaay to late, but have you tried turning of the echo and noise reduction? Had the same problem with Discord. (Micro + Systemsound => Cable Input, for Discord I set Cable Output as Input Device -> bad sound, turned the options off, got really nice sound)